# Extending controller in ExtJS 4 MVC application

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

I building my ExtJS 4 application following the MVC structure. I want to make an extendable grid MyGrid with some functionality that I can reuse several times. Therefore, I guess, it should have its own controller which is also extended, so that the functionality is inherited. How is this properly done?

In the code below I illustrate how I extend the controller MyGrid with MyExtendedGrid. I realize that I'm overriding the *init* function in the MyGrid controller, so that it is never called. Is the problem simply solved by calling the "super" *init* in MyGrid from MyExtendedGrid *init*, or merge the *control* objects? Is that the proper way to do this in the MVC spirit? If so, how?

controller/MyGrid.js :

```
Ext.define('App.controller.MyGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    refs: [
        {
            ref: 'myGridView',
            selector: 'mygrid'
        }
    ],
    init: function() {
        var me=this;
        me.control({
            'mygrid textfield[name=searchField]': {
                change: function() {
                    var view = me.getMyGridView();
                    // Do something with view
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

controller/MyExtendedGrid.js :

```
Ext.define('App.controller.MyExtendedGrid', {
    extend: 'App.controller.MyGrid',
    views: [
        'grids.MyExtendedGrid'],
    refs: [
        {
            ref: 'myExtendedGridView',
            selector: 'myextendedgrid'
        }
    ],
    init: function() {
        var me=this;
        me.control({
            'myextendedgrid': {
                // Some control code
                // Using getMyExtendedGridView()
            }
        });
    }
});
```

view/grids/MyGrid.js :

```
Ext.define('App.view.grids.MyGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.mygrid',
    requires: [
    ],
    store: '', // Not defined here
    columns: [ ], // Not defined here

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.tbar = [
            'Search',
            {
                 xtype: 'textfield',
                 name: 'searchField',
                 hideLabel: true,
                 width: 150
            }
        ];
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

view/grids/MyExtendedGrid.js :

```
Ext.define('App.view.grids.MyExtendedGrid', {
    extend: 'App.view.grids.MyGrid',
    alias : 'widget.myextendedgrid',
    store: 'MyStore',
    columns: [
        // ...
    ],

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.bbar = [
            //...
        ];
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some thinking I decided on the following solution, which has the advantage that mygrid does not need to know about myextendedgrid.

I extend my gridview as in the question.

I gave the base grid its own controller for doing common functionality, for instance `deleteButton.setDisable(false)` when something is selected in the grid.

Next, I remind myself that using `refs:[` (for instance with `selector: 'mygrid'`) would ambiguously point to both instances of the base class any extended instances. When using `me.control({` I instead get the relevant grid by traversing from the activated element using `up`:

```
me.control({
    'mygrid textfield[name=searchField]': {
        change: function(searchfield) {
            var grid=searchfield.up('mygrid'); // (mygrid or myextendedgrid!)
            // Do something with view
        }
    }
...
```

The extended grid I give its own controller and here I could use `refs`. I don't extend the controller from the MyGrid class (but rather from `'Ext.app.Controller'`), unless I would like to use functions or variables from the MyGrid controller. All the controllers are started from app.js using:

```
Ext.application({
    controllers: [
        'MyGrid'
        'MyExtendedGrid',
    ],
...
```

In order to get the grid when rows are selected in the grid, I stored the grid in the selection model as below:

In controller/MyGrid.js :

```
me.control({
    'mygrid': {
        afterrender: function(grid) {
            var selModel=grid.getSelectionModel();
            selModel.myGrid=grid;
        },
        selectionchange: function(selModel, selected, eOpts) {
            var grid=selModel.theLookupGrid;
            // Do something with view
        }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a bit trickier...

Here is what we did in our application (we have exact same situation - some kind of base controller, that is reused in many different places)

1. Keep init function in base controller.
2. Define common base method in this base controller (like gridRendered - where you need to do something for all controllers all the time).
3. Subscribe to the events in all child controllers but subscribe events using methods of base controller. It won't work otherwise - base controller doesn't have proper refs to properly subscribed to events.

I can post couple source snippets, but I think it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: @sha I would actually love it if you would post a code snippet or two.

Comment: @LeviHackwith: no problem. let's do this in separate question so we don't confuse this one. wanna post new question?

Comment: @sha I was looking for code snippet related to your solution. Do you still think it needs to be in a separate question? I'm just having a hard time visualizing the steps you list.

Comment: @LeviHackwith I think it will be less confusing to other people, because my answer is not marked as answer anymore... Looks like topic starter found another way

Comment: @sha http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628306/how-to-perform-controller-inheritance-in-extjs-4